# VueJS attach a static string to v-bind

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My use case is something like this.

1. I stored images names in an array called **imagesFolder**
2. then I retrieve names from that array and display on my vue component.

This is my code

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <div class="" v-for="image in imagesFolder">
      <img v-bind:src="image" alt=""  height="100px" width="auto"><br>
    </div>
  </div>

    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data(){
        return{
          imagesFolder:['src/assets/mickey.png','src/assets/logo.png']
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

My question is every time I have to store the static location part **src/assets/** instead of doing this. Is there a way to attach this **src/assets/** part to the `img` tag. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: You could do `v-bind:src="'src/assets' + image"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide just the filename of the images in an array in your `data`.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return{
        images: ['mickey', 'logo']
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Then, you can loop through and use only the filename of the image as the dynamic value.

```
<div class="" v-for="image in images">
  <img :src="`src/assets/${image}.png`" alt=""  height="100px" width="auto"><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html):

```
Vue.directive('src', function (el, binding) {
  el.src = 'src/assets/' + binding.value
})
```

Then you can use `v-src`:

```
<img v-src="image"
```

Now, you are safe to use just file name:

```
imagesFolder:['mickey.png','logo.png']
```